# Multiprocesing loop within class method

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I'm having problems running this code with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`.

This program takes in a list of values from an Excel file as strings. It iterates over those values and passes each to a function. The function then uses that value and runs several more functions to gather data from webscraping about the value, compiles it and adds the results onto a class attribute dict.

The code looks like this:

```
class RunControl():
    def __init__(self):
        wb = xw.Book('bookname.xlsx')
        self.sheetOne = wb.sheets['Sheet1']

        self.create_value_list = Value_Object_Generator() # create object that reads
                                                          # excel file
        self.create_value_list.create_value_objects() # method to read excel and format data

        self.value_list = self.create_value_list.li # list of values that needs iterated over
        self.var = self.create_value_list.var # variable to pass later

        self.outfile = {}

    def _process(self, value): # multithreading target process - receives value, creates
                               # value class and runs web-scrape
        acct = value

        do_run = Value_to_run(acct, self.var) # creates object of custom class that
                                              # contains the sub methods to run threaded
                                              # scraping functions
        do_run.web_scrape_async() # calls method to run threaded scraping

        returns = do_run.results # returns web responses as a list
        self.outfile[acct] = returns # Creates new key:val pair with the name of the
                                     # value : list

    def run_accounts(self):
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as executor:
            executor.map(self._process, self.value_list)

        return self.outfile
```

When I run the program `RunControl` instantiates but after that the program seems to hang. I'm not getting any tracebacks the program will just sit and not respond until I restart the kernel or close the CLI.

Any thoughts on what is causing this? Or better way to do this?

Comment: try a plain function outside the class, in previous Python versions there were problems if it's a method

Comment: Are you sure that `do_run.web_scrape_async()` works? I would validate its being passed an actual value, and that if passed said value it can execute and return. If you comment out parts of `_process()` (or all of it) does the program complete execution? I'm also not sure whether using a member function is a good idea, since I'm /pretty/ sure a copy of each object would need to be passed to your executor, or it would lock on the one copy you have, both of which could be bad news for a multithreaded app.

Comment: @NathanielFord, hmm. it is not working? When I run the .web_scrape_async() method without the processpool or multiprocessing it runs just fine. But it's not doing anything when called from the process pool...

Comment: @RandomB, I'm trying to re-write it. My only issue is I have to pass multiple arguments into the web_scrape_async() method and it looks like the map function only accepts one argument. I used the class so I can pass an attribute into the web_scrape_async instead of passing it through map() function.

Comment: Processes run in separate memory spaces, which means you can't instantiate a class instance in one and expect to execute its methods in another.

Comment: Just so you know, multiple processes are just that - different and distinct python processes (like if you did `python my_script.py` in the terminal, opened up another terminal, and did `python my_script.py` again) and they do not share state

Comment: So, the modification to `self.outfile[acct] = returns` will only affect the process that it's in.

Comment: "it looks like the map function only accepts one argument" then use `starmap`, or do your own argument unpacking from a tuple of arguments

Comment: You can also use `partial()` to supply extra arguments to a function to make it appear to only accept one.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty this was a great learning experience but I now have the answer and it's working beautifully in my program.

As several commenter pointed out; each process exists in its own memory place and doesn't share attributes or class methods between each other. This was the heart of my problem as I was trying to accesss methods and attributes from different processes.

To fix this I had to re-write my process function to instantiate each object when the function is called, then used the partial() function to pass the multiple attributes I needed. Partial allowed me to pass static data to every function, and instantiating a new object in each process and passing the static arguments made it work perfectly!

Thanks everyone!!